# Oracle: Selecting using inner select

Tags: oracle, select, group-by

I have the following example:

```
Select MAX(1) as foo, count(*) as bar From dual
```

This is executed properly by returning 1 as foo and 1 as bar.

Now I will create an inner select that returns only the foo, retaining the bar as it was in previous example.

```
Select (Select Max(1) as foo From dual), count(*) as bar From dual
```

The latter example will give the following error:

> ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

This can be easily fixed by providing a (redundant?) Group By:

```
 Select (Select Max(1) From dual) as foo, count(*) as bar From dual Group By 1
```

My question is the following: Since we certainly return a single row in inner select (by providing the MAX aggregated function) why is necessary to declare a group by at the end of the statement? Also, will this group by addition have an effect in statement's performance?

Answer (score 1):

In the first case

> Select MAX(1) as foo, count(*) as bar From dual

you do not need a group by expression, because you have two aggregate functions and no other values.

In the second case

> Select (Select Max(1) From dual) as foo, count(*) as bar From dual Group By 1

suddenly one of the selected values is not an aggregate function but some kind of another value - a subquery result set in particular - and Oracle can't know how many values that result set will have. So you need to have a group by on it.

The performance impact will not be caused by the group by per se, but by the subquery. In the first example you will have only one scan of DUAL, and in the second - you will have TWO table scans - one for the subquery and one for the main query. You can see that in the execution plans.

Comment: As I mentioned to Stawros, I just cannot find out the reason oracle does not know that inner select will by definition return a single value .

Comment: It is just not that smart :)
For the database the subquery is interpreted just as another table ( or more actually a view ) and is handled as such.

Comment: A result set is what it is - a result set. By definition it can have multiple values in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `over` directive in count() -

```
Select (Select Max(1) as foo From dual) as foo, count(*) over() as bar
  From dual
```

Comment: Actually I don't want an alternative solution, I just want to know if there is a certain reason Oracle does not know that the inner select will by declaration return a single value.